# Template class variables appear corrupt when inspected but are in fact valid when printed

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I have a template class in my framework that started reporting invalid/corrupt/bad_ptr values for variables when inspected in debug mode. The variables however, appear correct when printed to console.

I found that four factors seem critical to this situation occurring:

- Built in debug using /MDd runtime library (/MTd seems unaffected)
- Run after a rebuild all
- The inclusion of the #define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0 macro
- The ifstream object in the constructor

In the following example the constructor argument str should appear corrupted/invalid/bad_ptr when inspected but will print to console correctly. Removing any one of the above factors rectifies the problem.

```
#define _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING 0

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo(std::string str)
  {
    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    std::ifstream in;
  }
};

int main()
{
   Foo<int> MyFoo("Hello World");
   return 0;
}
```

My questions is that is this simply a VS2010 bug or is there something I'm doing that's causing this?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Seems to be a problem with VS2010 as I tested this in VS2008 as well without problems.

Comment: Just to update, I just ran this on VS2005 and it seemed fine. I agree that it seems to be a VS2010 specific issue.